# Is using Past Perfect obligatory?

Tags: grammar, past-vs-past-perfect

Here are, suppose, two sentences:

> Before she went to college, Bridget waited tables to save up for her tuition.
>
> Before she went to college, Bridget **had** waited tables to save up
>   for her tuition.

Are both of them correct? Is using Past Perfect mandatory?

Comment: Half of English speakers would probably use the first and the other half the second. It might depend partly on the context. If Bridget had died, the past perfect would definitely be preferable. In an exam, I would use the second.

Comment: @RonaldSole What do grammar books say?

Comment: Hey Sergey, did that answers your doubt?

Comment: @artu-hnrq I'm sorry, but I can't press the check button next to an answer that contains multiple errors ('strait', 'can describes', etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As brings [this reference](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/) mentioned in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/233045/105169):

> In standard English, we use the past perfect to discuss events which
>   **were completed** before some other event.

This way your first sentence don't formally clarify if Bridged is still waiting, even though she had decided to go to college. Otherwise, the second phrase ensures she stops waiting it.

Observe that the context measure, and colloquially we don't use the language in that strait formal manner, therefore it can describes she stops waiting for that moment and returns to do this after a while.

Thus, the second sentence (in complement of the first) could brings the idea that she (maybe momentarily) give up of waiting that and went to the college without keep this concern in mind. Or yet to emphasize she made what she could until run out of time to wait, because of her appointments. Of course, as mentioned in [Ronald's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/233044/is-using-past-perfect-obligatory#comment442759_233044), these interpretations are context dependents.

So, **Are both of them correct?** Yes, both are correct and they express similar (but not identical) ideas. And **Is using Past Perfect mandatory?** I would say that, depending of what you want to express, yes it is; *Simple past* is called this way exactly because doesn't carry too much meaning of the sentence as other past times can do.

> Before say goodbye, I hope I **had** helped